# Elastic (Young's) modulus and shear modulus derived from interatomic potential

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy, material-science, elasticity

Based on figure shown here, a theoretical elastic modulus can be derived by considering the interatomic potential and taking the derivative of the potential energy with respect to the distance (x-direction), close to the equilibrium position of the atoms ($x_0$) .

(Figure source: S. Veprek et al. Towards the understanding of mechanical properties of super-and ultrahard nanocomposites. Journal of Vacuum Science & Technology B 2002 Mar;20(2):650-64.)

[image]
I was wondering, if we add an extra position axis (in-screen y-axis) to the interatomic potential making it a 3D function (a potential energy surface), is it possible to derive the shear modulus if the derivative of the potential energy with respect to the y-direction is taken?

Since both derivatives (respect to x and y) are equal to the force in that direction, another figure is added below for clarity showing the forces and an exaggerated deformation. In this lattice, the bottom row atoms are fixed in position. On the top row atoms, forces are acted, in one case in the x-direction (elastic deformation) and in the other case in the y-direction (shear deformation). Can a theoretically calculated 3D potential energy surface (by quantum chemical methods for instance) also give the theoretical elastic and shear modulus by taking the derivative of the potential energy in the x (elastic) and y (shear) directions?
[image]

Comment: Since the first figure is pretty notional at best (it does not represent the real 3-D bonding potential of a material),yes and no. If you had a good physics-based model of a crystal, one could in principle derive elastic and shear moduli from it.